# Issue With Asp.net Webforms Multithreading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, webforms

We are running into issues with a custom web server control. The premise behind the control is to allow parallel execution of whatever elements are wrapped in this control. For example: we could have two repeaters on a page each wrapped in an AsyncLoadPanel and when the page loads each repeater's content would be loaded in a separate thread and then joined afterwards when both threads have finished. This would make it so the page takes as long to load as the longest running thread.

The issue we're experiencing is when multiple users are logged on to the same page at the same time weird exceptions start to show up in the event viewer(samples below) and w3wp eventually crashes, killing everyone's sessions and kicking them off the site.

My gut tells me these threads are stepping all over each other when multiple users are on the same page. The problem is I don't understand this code well enough to know what could be causing the issue. Any insight as to potential issues would be greatly appreciated.

I should also note that we have several AsyncLoadPanels running on this page along with some regular UpdatePanels.

Also, the spinlocks were not there in the original design of this control. They were added in an attempt to mitigate this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestSite.usercontrols.GenericControls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:AsyncLoadPanel runat=server></{0}:AsyncLoadPanel>")]
    [PersistChildren(false)]
    [ParseChildren(false)]
    public class AsyncLoadPanel : PlaceHolder, INamingContainer
    {
        //private IAsyncResult asyncResult;

    //private Thread thread = null;

    protected static List<Thread> Threads = new List<Thread>();

    protected static SpinLock LoadCompleteLock = new SpinLock();

    public delegate void AsyncLoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs during the OnLoad event.
    /// </summary>
    public event AsyncLoadHandler AsyncLoad;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the AsyncLoad event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected virtual void OnAsyncLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AsyncLoad != null)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                HttpContext.Current = context;
                AsyncLoad(this, e);
            });

            //thread.Start();

            Threads.Add(thread);

            this.Page.LoadComplete += PageOnLoadComplete;
        }
    }

    private void PageOnLoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //if (thread != null)
        //{
        //    thread.Join();
        //    thread = null;
        //}

        // We don't have any threads so short circuit this
        if (Threads.Count == 0)
            return;

        bool lockEntered = false;               // We're not really using this, we just have to pass it to the spin lock.

        LoadCompleteLock.Enter(ref lockEntered);

        // This is not redundant with the previous check. This is incase two threads both to to the lock. We still need the other check to get us out with out blocking.
        if (Threads.Count == 0)
            return;

        var startedThreads = new List<Thread>(Threads);
        Threads.Clear();            // This ensures that we don't try and do this again when PageOnLoadComplete for another control is run.

        LoadCompleteLock.Exit();

        foreach (var thread in startedThreads)
            //if (thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted)
                thread.Start();

        foreach (var thread in startedThreads)
            thread.Join();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        OnAsyncLoad(null);

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
<Test:AsyncLoadPanel runat="server" ID="alpContent" OnAsyncLoad="alpContent_OnAsyncLoad">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ServiceRepeater">
    <!--Do some stuff-->
    </asp:Repeater>
</Test:AsyncLoadPanel>

protected void alpContent_OnAsyncLoad(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {

        var product = ((systemdetail)Page).Product;

        ServiceRepeater.DataSource = product.ProductChildren.DefaultView;
        ServiceRepeater.ItemDataBound += ServiceRepeater_ItemDataBound;                
        ServiceRepeater.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromContext(HttpContext.Current).Raise(ex);            
    }
}
```

**Sample Exceptions**

Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(System.String)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.BuildUrl(System.Func`1)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Url()
   at CustomerPortal.usercontrols.SystemDetails.ServicesTab.alpContent_OnAsyncLoad(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT

Process ID: 5180

Exception: System.ArgumentException

Message: Value does not fall within the expected range.

StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.BuildUrl(Func`1 pathAccessor)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Url()
   at CustomerPortal.usercontrols.SystemDetails.ServicesTab.alpContent_OnAsyncLoad(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: I think, you (whoever tries or tried) to do this, have a design issue on your hands. If I understand your question right. Seem that you doing big disfavor to ASP.net by trying to multi threading during page life-cycle. It would be more robust approach to load page in its thinnest form, and then let controls use AJAX to load their pieces of data asynchronously.